# iOS: open text file with not text extension

Tags: ios, file, text-editor

Trying to get SSH private key from *.pk file.

Currently use app to extract this file from "external source" and it gives me an options to open this file in mail app / dropbox / btsync but not in notes app, for example.

Is there any tool / app to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being able to do that with [iEditor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ieditor-text-code-editor/id562162723?mt=8) - the only program to open any file as text.

Comment: Could you please explain how to open a file from local files on iPad in this app?